# inserting information and image in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

please help guys i have code for inserting name and etc.. and for inserting a  image i cant combine the codes

here is the ouput in phpmyadmin i only insert one value thou...

[image]

thanks for your help guys

```
<---!THIS CODE BELOW IT INSERT ID,NAME AND ETC --->
<?php
require 'db.php';
$message = '';
$Error = '';
if (isset ($_POST['Attendee_id'])  && 
isset($_POST['RFID_number']) &&
isset($_POST['Attendee_Name']) &&
isset($_POST['CourseOrDepartment']) &&
isset ($_POST['Status']) ) {

$Attendee_id = $_POST['Attendee_id'];
$RFID_number = $_POST['RFID_number'];
$Attendee_Name = $_POST['Attendee_Name'];
$CourseOrDepartment = $_POST['CourseOrDepartment'];
$Status = $_POST['Status'];
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_listofregister(Attendee_id, 
RFID_number,Attendee_Name,CourseOrDepartment,Status)
VALUES(:Attendee_id, 
:RFID_number,:Attendee_Name,:CourseOrDepartment,:Status)';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
if ($statement->execute([':Attendee_id' => $Attendee_id, ':RFID_number' => 
$RFID_number,':Attendee_Name' => $Attendee_Name,':CourseOrDepartment' => 
 $CourseOrDepartment,':Status' => $Status])) {
 $message = 'DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY';
 }
 else
 {
 $Error = "ID SHOULD BE UNIQUE";
 }
 }
 ?>
 <---! HERE IS FOR IMAGE --->

 <?php

 $msg = '';
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 $image = $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'];
 $img = file_get_contents($image);
 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dbattendancelibrary') or 
 die('Unable To connect');
 $sql = "insert into tbl_listofregister (image) values(?)";
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s",$img);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
 if($check==1){
 $msg = 'Image Successfullly UPloaded';
 }else{
 $msg = 'Error uploading image';
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Holy painful lack of indentation .... ;) BTW... whats the problem? Errors? Results of what you tried? You sort of left us hanging there on what exactly is not going well...

Comment: Just modify the first bit of code and add the lines that get the uploaded file, and then add the column image (and it's value) to your INSERT statement.

Comment: Why store the image in the table? Just store the path to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would combine the two inserts into one action. But I would advise against storing the images in the db. Store the path relative to your site of the image instead.

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
$message = '';
$Error = '';
if(isset($_POST['Attendee_id'])  && 
    isset($_POST['RFID_number']) &&
    isset($_POST['Attendee_Name']) &&
    isset($_POST['CourseOrDepartment']) &&
    isset($_POST['Status']) &&
    isset($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name']) &&
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    $Attendee_id = $_POST['Attendee_id'];
    $RFID_number = $_POST['RFID_number'];
    $Attendee_Name = $_POST['Attendee_Name'];
    $CourseOrDepartment = $_POST['CourseOrDepartment'];
    $Status = $_POST['Status'];
    $image = $_FILES['Image']['tmp_name'];
    $img = file_get_contents($image);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_listofregister(
        Attendee_id,
        RFID_number,
        Attendee_Name,
        CourseOrDepartment,
        Status,
        image)
    VALUES(:Attendee_id, 
        :RFID_number,
        :Attendee_Name,
        :CourseOrDepartment,
        :Status,
        :Image)';
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    if($statement->execute(
            [':Attendee_id' => $Attendee_id, 
            ':RFID_number' => $RFID_number,
            ':Attendee_Name' => $Attendee_Name,
            ':CourseOrDepartment' => $CourseOrDepartment,
            ':Status' => $Status,
            ':Image' => $img]
        )) {
        $message = 'DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY';
    } else {
        $Error = "ID SHOULD BE UNIQUE";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I gave you a vote just for fixing that completely wrecked indentation.

Comment: So Jeffery, did this answer work for you? If so, please accept the answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
$Attendee_id = $_POST['Attendee_id'];
$RFID_number = $_POST['RFID_number'];
$Attendee_Name = $_POST['Attendee_Name'];
$CourseOrDepartment = $_POST['CourseOrDepartment'];
$Status = $_POST['Status'];
```

After these lines , you can add this line for an img

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "filename/".$_FILES['file']['name']);

Then, add it in the query as ( $_FILES['file']['name'] ).

in HTML file write this line (  ).

I hope it's work well <3

Comment: This allows anyone to upload any file to any location on your filesystem. Probably a bad plan.